# An object reference is required for the non-static field...etc

Tags: c#, non-static

I have looked at all the similar questions that have already been answered on this topic, but I couldn't find an answer that solved my exact problem.

```
private void Subscribe2Data()
    {
        // Define parameters for Subscribe method:
        //int itemIndex;

        //initialize the client subscription handle
        clientSubscriptionHandle = 1;

        //Paramter to specify if the subscription will be added as active or not
        bool active = true;

        // The updateRate parameter is used to tell the server how fast we
        // would like to see data updates.
        int updateRate = 1000;

        // The deadband parameter specifies the minimum deviation needed
        // to be considered a change of value. 0 is disabled
        Single deadBand = 0;

        // The revisedUpdateRate parameter is the actual update rate that the
        // server will be using.
        int revisedUpdateRate;


        //Initialize the item identifier values
        itemIdentifiers[0] = new ItemIdentifier();
        itemIdentifiers[0].ClientHandle = 0;
        itemIdentifiers[0].DataType = Type.GetType("System.int16");
        itemIdentifiers[0].ItemName = "Channel1.Device1.Data1";


        itemIdentifiers[1] = new ItemIdentifier();
        itemIdentifiers[1].ClientHandle = 1;
        itemIdentifiers[1].DataType = Type.GetType("System.int16");
        itemIdentifiers[1].ItemName = "Channel1.Device1.Data2";


        itemValues[0] = new ItemValue();
        itemValues[0].Value = temp;

        ReturnCode returnCode;
        try
        {
            returnCode = DaServerMgt.WriteAsync(clientSubscriptionHandle, ref itemIdentifiers, itemValues);
            if (returnCode != ReturnCode.SUCCEEDED)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write request failed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WriteAsync exception. Reason: ", ex);
        }
```

Near the bottom, where it says returnCode = DaServerMgt.WriteAsync..etc. I am getting the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property" on that line.  Looking at the answers to other similar questions, I tried making my method static by changing "private void Subscribe2Data()" to "private static void Subscrive2Data()."

Doing that made every single one of my variables in that method have the object reference error as opposed to just the DaServerMgt.WriteAsync line.

So then I tried to make an entirely separate method with the ReturnCode return code section in it instead of the Subscribe2Data method and made the new method static, but the error was still there.

I also tried

```
 ReturnCode returnCode;
        try
        {
            Service1 p = new Service1();
            returnCode = p.DaServerMgt.WriteAsync(clientSubscriptionHandle, ref itemIdentifiers, itemValues);
            if (returnCode != ReturnCode.SUCCEEDED)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write request failed");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WriteAsync exception. Reason: ", ex);
        }
```

EDIT: That does fix the "object reference.." error but now that I'm using the class (my bad) that gives other errors saying Service1 does not contain a definistion for DaServerMgt..etc.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot initialize an instance of a method, you have to do it for the class _**owning**_ the method.

Comment: Where is the code for this? `DaServerMgt.WriteAsync`

Comment: Pro-tip. Just avoid using `static`. Not a hard and fast rule, but you can get into some *really* bad habits with it.

Comment: You need to instantiate an object of DaServerMgt, not the method that it's being called in.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET he isn't using static, that's why it's throwing.

Comment: Also, WriteAsync should return a task, that you're not waiting for, or using the result of

Comment: Your problem does not seem to be the `Subscribe2Data()` method, but rather the `DaServerMgt.WriteAsync()` method. Please show us the declaration for that.

Comment: Note that all of your `Type.GetType("System.int16")` declarations are returning `null` because `System.int16` has a typo and should have a capital "I", like so: `Type.GetType("System.Int16")`. Personally I would use `typeof(Int16)` instead of parsing a string.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET what bad habits? I use static for utility methods, factory methods, etc...

Comment: @SteveG And those are proper uses for static (not to mention extension methods). Its just easy for inexperienced programmers to overuse it (especially when state is involved) and cause problems for the next poor chap who has to modify/deal with the code and/or cause bugs when people don't realize that `static` means state is shared across all instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is that `DaServerMgt.WriteAsync()` isn't static but you're trying to call it like it is. You need to instantiate the `DaServerMgt` class and then call the `WriteAsync()` method on that instance.

```
DaServerMgt server = new DaServerMgt();
returnCode = server.WriteAsync(clientSubscriptionHandle, ref itemIdentifiers, itemValues);
```

Your 2nd attempt won't work because you can't instantiate (`new`) a method, only a constructor.

In all cases, making your class static isn't necessary.

Comment: Note for OP that it would be smart to search the solution for "new DaServerMgt" and to use the one that's already instantiated (if there is one) in case it contains state. Just instantiating and using a whole new one may cause it's own problems.

Comment: + using a task as if it were a result, but thats not a problem until he fixes the whole static thing

Comment: Thank you! This makes it so I can at least compile the program which is further than I've gotten in awhile

Comment: @KatieJ glad to hear. Don't forget to mark the answer correct if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Making `Subscribe2Data()` will not solve this problem.

The problem is that in the class `DaServerMgt`, the function `WriteAsync()` is not a static function. That means that you need to have an instance of `DaServerMgt` when you call this function in `Subscribe2Data()`.

Comment: Making `Subscribe2Data()` static won't help if `DaServerMgt` isn't instantiated or if its `WriteAsync()` method is not made static.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, you are correct, of course. Some confusion on my part while writing the answer. Will edit.